# After ios updated to ios 11.0 my geolocator doesn't work, xamarin.forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using geolocator to get user position but, After ios update to ios 11.0, my geolocator doesn't work...
In android it works fine, and it worked before the update in ios as well
this is my class for geolocator

```
using neoFly_Montana.Model;
using Plugin.Geolocator;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace neoFly_Montana.Api
{
class Geolocator
{
    public static async Task<Localizacao> GetUserLocationAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

            //try
            //{
                var auxPosition = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            //} catch(Exception e)
            //{
            //    var i = e.Message;
            //}

            if (auxPosition == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            else {
                Localizacao position = new Localizacao();
                position.latitude = auxPosition.Latitude;
                position.longitude = auxPosition.Longitude;

                //teste joyce iphone
               // position.latitude = -22.8899748;//-23.5505199;
              //  position.longitude = -47.0713897;// -46.6333094;//


                return position;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var teste = ex.Message;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

after call this line

```
                var auxPosition = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

it stops working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation of the plugin](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/GettingStarted.html) you need to add a new privacy related plist entry.

> If targeting iOS 11 you may need to add: **NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription**

There is [an issue](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin/issues/160) added to the project related to this.